IMU odometry in rviz starting from a bag file (No TF data)
I'm working on a project where I need to read IMU data from a .bag file of a RealSense D435i and obtain its spatial position through filters like those in imu_tools to visualize it in Rviz (together with what the camera sees).
My issue is that the .bag file provided to me (since I don't own a RealSense, I didn't record it) apparently doesn't contain TF transformations, which, from what I've read, are necessary to obtain IMU references in space.
Is it necessary to set a particular frame for the d435i, and if so, how can I set a Fixed Frame different from the default one?
So far, what I've managed to do is write a ROS node that prints on-screen what is being published on /camera/imu, a topic containing linear acceleration and angular velocity in real-time (relative to the bag time).
When I run the bag and open Rviz, selecting the topic /camera/color/image_raw, I correctly see the recorded video.
How should I use the imu_tools filters to obtain the correct visualization in Rviz?
These might seem like basic questions, but it's my first experience with ROS, and I don't know where to start.
Thanks!
This is the node i wrote:
#include <rosbag/bag.h>
#include <rosbag/view.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>
#include <ros/ros.h>
void imuCallback(const sensor_msgs::Imu::ConstPtr& imu_msg) {
std::cout << "Orientazione: [" 
          << imu_msg->orientation.x << ", " 
          << imu_msg->orientation.y << ", "
          << imu_msg->orientation.z << ", "
          << imu_msg->orientation.w << "]" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Velocità angolare: [" 
          << imu_msg->angular_velocity.x << ", " 
          << imu_msg->angular_velocity.y << ", "
          << imu_msg->angular_velocity.z << "]" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Accelerazione lineare: [" 
          << imu_msg->linear_acceleration.x << ", " 
          << imu_msg->linear_acceleration.y << ", "
          << imu_msg->linear_acceleration.z << "]" << std::endl;

}
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
ros::init(argc, argv, "imu_reader");
ros::NodeHandle nh;

// Subscribes to topic /camera/imu
ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Imu>("/camera/imu", 1000, imuCallback);

ros::spin();

return 0;

}

Please format your code correctly
